# Single MySQL session per python\django process

Tags: mysql, django, session, session-variables

If at the start of a python\django program I load a module that executes a raw custom sql command such as

```
from django.db import connection
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("SET SESSION wait_timeout=2147483")
```

thus changing a **session** variable, will it hold for all the rest of the program run? i.e. is the module in the same MySQL session as the rest of the code running in the same python\django process?

Answer (score 10):

Not reliably.

The correct way to do this is to use `init_command` within the `OPTIONS` dictionary of the db settings:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        ...
        'OPTIONS': {
            'init_command': '"SET SESSION wait_timeout=2147483',
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: Daniel, could you elaborate why "not reliably"?

Comment: Because there isn't really any concept in Django of 'start'. A new process can be started any time by the server itself, and there aren't really any hooks to tie into that process at the moment.